# Get latest N posts for each user

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have 2 tables in my db, `User` and `Post`. the first table is storing users personal data and the second table is storing posts by users.

I want to build 1 query to get the latest N posts for each user, I was able to get them with multiple queries by looping through each user and get the latest posts and store them in array for later but the performance was too bad and I can't relay on it because too many users and posts (more than 20000 users).

So I need some dynamic query to get these posts, of course I will add some pagination for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be fine (performance-wise) to get the latest posts per user, especially if you're going to be using pagination. Did you forget to add indexes on your tables? Use `EXPLAIN .. ` to see if MySQL is able to run your query efficiently.

Comment: You could try adding a date filter to your SELECt, assuming you have a date field to work with.

Comment: This is the so called *n out of m* problem, thou i failed to find any article on it and the project i used this in is beyond my reach :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on JOIN to write a single query against multiple tables.

for example: `select post from posts join users on posts.poster_id = users.user_id`

For good performance, make sure your indexes are set correctly, typically on poster_id but it also depends on what columns you use in your where clause.

You can add the where clause to the end of that to only return posts from a certain time or user. Pagination is more tricky and depends on the DB you're using.

Pagination I use (in SqlServer 2008r2, using Sql2012 can be done differently):

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time DESC) as RowNum, * from <query>) as RowConstrainedResult 
WHERE RowNum >= X AND RowNum < Y 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

where you replace columns, query, and X and Y with relevant row numbers (eg 101 and 200)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I thought for JOIN but I faced one problem, How I can apply pagination for it because this query will return posts for all users, right??

Comment: I'm sure you already knew that adding "where user_id = 10" to this query will return data for just 1 user and you're not just blindly hacking in whatever answer SO gives you to support 20,000 users....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user, p.posts FROM user u
LEFT JOIN Post p
ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL.  The following will get you the last ten posts for each user, with the post ids in a comma separated list:

```
select p.userid,
       substring_index(group_concat(p.postid order by postdate desc), ',', 10) as lastten
from posts p
group by p.userid;
```